# Display authors Whos write in category

Tags: wordpress, author

i have block that display all category in custom post type of my site like this:-

```
$cat = get_terms( "progamdvideo_c", $args ) ;
```

now in post type i add article, each article have authors, how can display him in this block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to show author list by filtering empty post users. It may help u,

```
<?php wp_list_authors('show_fullname=1&optioncount=1&orderby=post_count&order=DESC&number=3'); ?>
```